# Writing a method inside the selector?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, methods, performselector

This is probably crazy, but I'm wondering whether or not we can write the actual method inside a selector. Reason being, I just have a simple 1-liner for my method.

```
-(void)doThat {
    loadedPhoto.alpha = 1.0;
}

-(IBAction)revealPickers:(id)sender {

    loadedPhoto.alpha = 0.7;
    [self performSelector:@selector(doThat) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

So what I'd like to know is there a shortcut to this like (obviously this won't work):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(^(void){loadedPhoto.alpha=1.0;}) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

Possible or just stupid?

Comment: What about `dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){loadedPhoto.alpha = 1.0});`?

Comment: you can use `class_addMethods` and `imp_implementationWithBlock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on and correcting my comment:

My comment is wrong, I misread your code and thought you were doing `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:etc:]`.

My actual solution (after a quick googling - it wasn't that hard to find):

```
// Delay execution of my block for 10 seconds.
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^(void){
    loadedPhoto.alpha = 1.0;
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Boom! This works perfectly. Thanks for others' comments but Imma gonna vote this as answer. Thanks ALL!

Answer (score 0):

The easist solution is to use `dispatch_after` but you can also define the methods on `NSObject` using a block adapter.

```
@interface BlockAdapter

@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) void (^block)();

- (void)call;

@end

@implementation BlockAdapter

- (void)call {
    self.block();
}

@end
```

```
@interface NSObject (PerformBlocks)

- (void)performBlock:((void)^())block afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;

@end

@implementation NSObject (PerformBlocks)

- (void)performBlock:((void)^())block afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay {
   BlockAdapter* adapter = [[BlockAdapter alloc] init];
   adapter.block = block;

   [adapter performSelector:@selector(call) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];
}

@end
```

Comment: "The easist solution is to use dispatch_after" That is assuming the code is running in a dispatch queue

Comment: @newacct The most common case is running code in the main thread, then `dispatch_after` is the most straightforward solution.